# Azure App Service Tiers that Permanently Store Diagnostics Data

Tags: azure, storage, diagnostic, azure-web-apps

I need to permanently store diagnostic data for my webapp. I'm currently running in the Basic tier. If I upgrade to standard or premium, will either of those guarantee permanent diagnostic data storage? I can't find anything on this from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure all of the tiers offer some local storage and it is permanent. 
More over, you can write logs to Azure storage independent of your tier. (that is permanent as well).